# facet_grid for FeatureScatter for each cluster

Tags: r, ggplot2, seurat

I wonder if it's possible to make a `facet_grid` plot for each cluster within the `FeatureScatter` function. The two features that I want to plot is defined by feature1 and feature2 and the facets should be the clusters within my object defined as levels within `pbmc.big$seurat_clusters`.

```
FeatureScatter(object = pbmc.big,
               feature1 = "MALAT1",
               feature2 = "percent.mito",
               plot.cor = T)
```

Comment: You may wish to indicate which package the `FeatureScatter` function came from, how to reproduce your `pmbc.big` object, and what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

It's worth mentioning the data you used can downloaded from [this link](https://cf.10xgenomics.com/samples/cell/pbmc3k/pbmc3k_filtered_gene_bc_matrices.tar.gz) and created like this:

```
library(Seurat)
library(magrittr)

pbmc.big <- Read10X(data.dir = "../data/pbmc3k/filtered_gene_bc_matrices/hg19/")
pbmc.big <- CreateSeuratObject(counts = pbmc.big)
pbmc.big$percent.mito = PercentageFeatureSet(pbmc.big,pattern="^MT-")
```

Run the clustering:

```
pbmc.big = pbmc.big %>% 
SCTransform() %>% 
RunPCA() %>% 
RunTSNE(dims=1:15) %>% 
FindNeighbors(dims=1:15) %>% 
FindClusters(res=0.1)
```

You can facet like this:

```
g = FeatureScatter(object = pbmc.big,
               feature1 = "MALAT1",
               feature2 = "percent.mito",
               plot.cor = TRUE)

g + facet_wrap(~colors)
```

[image]

The correlation is missing, if you need that, one way is to pull out the variables and make the plot:

```
library(ggpubr)

data.frame(cluster = Idents(pbmc.big),
MALAT1 = FetchData(pbmc.big,"MALAT1"),
percent.mito = FetchData(pbmc.big,"percent.mito")) %>%
ggplot(aes(x=MALAT1 , y=  percent.mito, col = cluster)) +
geom_point(size=1) +
facet_wrap(~cluster)+
stat_cor(method = "pearson")
```

[image]